# Why am I getting 'http://localhost:3000/?' route when using useNavigate in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am using `useNavigate` to navigate from one page of my website to another when a button is clicked. When I run the site using npm start, when I click the button, the page reloads the current page and the url changes from 'http://localhost:3000' to 'http://localhost:3000/?'

The code is below:

```
const submitForm = async (e) => {
const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/properties")
const jsonData = await res.json()
setProperties(jsonData)
navigate("/list", { state: properties })
}
```

button element:

```
<button onClick={() => submitForm()}>Find Properties</button>
```

For configuring my routes in App.js, I simply have:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<FormComponent />} />
          <Route path="/list" element={<ListComponent />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

Comment: are you having any type of issue? or you are asking just for curiosity

Comment: I guess you might want to preventDefault the submission.... `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: <button type='button' so the button doesn't submit the form. Better then submitting and preventing the submit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

1. It seems this button is very likely rendered within a `form` element, and when the form is submitted the default form action is ***not*** being prevented and the page is reloading.
2. Additionally, it appears the `submitForm` handler is enqueueing a React state update and then attempting to navigate with the expected updated state.

   ```
   const submitForm = async (e) => {
     const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/properties");
     const jsonData = await res.json();
     setProperties(jsonData);                  // <-- enqueued state update
     navigate("/list", { state: properties }); // <-- stale state
   }
   ```

   In React, enqueued state updates are processed asynchronously. You can't enqueue a state update and expect to read the updated state value in the same function/callback scope the update was enqueued in.
3. `button` elements have `type="submit"` by default if a `type` attribute isn't provided.

## Solution

1. Move the `submitForm` callback handler to the `form` element's `onSubmit` handler prop.
2. Call `preventDefault` on the `onSubmit` event object.
3. Explicitly declare a button type.
4. Pass the fetched JSON data directly in the `navigate` function, no need to update local state considering the component is likely unmounted soon.

Example:

```
const submitForm = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent default form action

  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/properties");
  const jsonData = await res.json();

  navigate("/list", { state: jsonData }); // <-- pass current data
}

...

<form onSubmit={submitForm}>
  ...

  <button type="submit">Find Properties</button>
  ...
</form>
```